# Writing a Mongo Converter for only one field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have the case that i have a simple POJO with one long field in it, which is actually a timestamp.

This field must be in the mongo database represented by an ISODate.

I could write an Converter fot the whole Pojo, but since it is only one field out of 25 that would not make much sense and is another spot for errors when a field would change or one more gets added.

Is there a way to call the default converter service and change the 2 other after the default converting service which will impact the performance a lot.
Or is there a default Converter interface to override?

Whats the best practice here?

Maybe there is an annotation that I can apply to this field?

And yes i could also write an LongToDate Converter, but this would affect all POJOs, not just this single one.

Here the sample POJO:

```
public class Person {
   private long someTimestamp;
//getters and setters
}
```

Without converters this would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ae8eede4b0249cde22059e"),
    "someTimestamp" : NumberLong(1392714950940)
}
```

Thats how the result should look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ae8eede4b0249cde22059e"),
    "someTimestamp" : ISODate("2013-12-23T23:00:00.000Z")
}
```

The desribed problem gets even more complicated when such a timestampt value is in a nested document for exmaple:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ae8eede4b0249cde22059e"),
    "items" : [
        "someTimestamp" : NumberLong(1392714950940)
    ]
}
```

POJO:

```
public class Person {
   private Collection<OtherPojoThatHoldsTimestamps> items;
//getters and setters
}
```

Maybe I should mention that I am using Spring to accomplish this. (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you need annotation-driven conversion. Section 6.6.2 in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) talks about this for formatters, and even has an example with timestamps.

The general idea is that you'd mark fields which need special handling with an annotation (it's a good use of annotations, you're specifying metadata after all). You'd then register a converter for fields having that annotation.

Problem is I've just tried this and can't get it to work, because metadata is getting lost. I've filed a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-889) to see whether there's a way around this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you provide a little example?

Comment: Ignore this for now. I've spent a couple of hours going through `ConversionService` implementations to understand what's going on, for my own sanity, and `Formatter`s won't help you for two reasons, (a) you're not converting to/from a `String` if you want a `Date` to get sent to MongoDB, and (b) Spring Data MongoDB uses a `DefaultConversionService`, not a `DefaultFormattingConversionService` for this reason. But I have an idea, will update soon.

Comment: I'm stumped. I got as far as trying a `ConditionalGenericConverter` which should work in theory, but annotations don't get propagated deep enough to work, and it all fails miserably. I'm opening a ticket, I'm really curious what Oliver G. and Juergen H. think of this.

Comment: i was at the same point, tried out many other things, nice to hear that i am not the last one who ended here

Comment: 4 years later, no comments on the Jira ticket.  :/

Answer (score 5):

the solution one is to use spring data mongodb listener:

```
package com.rc.user.auth.model.listener;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser;
import com.rc.user.auth.model.OAuth2AccessTokenEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AbstractMongoEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AfterConvertEvent;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.BeforeSaveEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.ParseException;

@Component
public class OAuth2AccessTokenEntityListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<OAuth2AccessTokenEntity> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<OAuth2AccessTokenEntity> event) {
        OAuth2AccessTokenEntity oat = event.getSource();
        DBObject db = event.getDBObject();

        db.put("tokenValue", oat.getJwt().serialize());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterConvert(AfterConvertEvent<OAuth2AccessTokenEntity> event) {

        OAuth2AccessTokenEntity oat = event.getSource();
        DBObject db = event.getDBObject();

       try {
          oat.setJwt(JWTParser.parse(db.get("tokenValue").toString()));
      } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the solution two is to use converter:

```
package com.rc.user.auth.model.convert;

import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter;


@WritingConverter
public class JWTToStringConverter implements Converter<JWT, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(JWT jwt) {
        return jwt.serialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Solution 1 finally worked for me after hours of messing around with MongoConverters

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Data MongoDB 3.2, there seems to be no way to easily define a field specific (not global) type converter.

[The type converters registered through the overriden `configureConverters()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters.xml) method in the configuration bean affect all the domain object.

But you can use a simple workaround using different types for field and accessor methods(getter/setter) to accomplish what you want.

```java
public class Person{
  
  @AccessType(AccessType.Type.FIELD)
  private Instant timestamp;
  
  public long getTimestamp() {
    return this.timestamp.getEpochSecond();
  }
  
  public void setTimestamp(final long ts) {
    this.timestamp = Instant.ofEpochSecond(ts);
  }
}
```

In the above code, persistency mapper to MongoDB will see `java.time.Instant` type
field and the `timestamp` field will be mapped to `Date`(`ISODate`) type in MongoDB.

But, other Java programs will access the `Person.timestamp` field via `long` type, because the getter and setter uses `long` type.

Although this approach is not so fancy to use field level annotations (if exists), it is simple and intuitive.

[`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is one of the essential classes for date/time after Java 8. It seems to be the best fit for timestamp in Java.  Spring Data MongoDB provided built-in type mapping for both `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant` to/from MongoDB's `date`(`Date`, `ISODate`) type.

Below is a sample domain object from my program. Lombok is applied. In the domain object, `java.math.BigInteger` type is mapped to MongoDB's [`decimal`(`Decimal128`) type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(collection = "transactions")
public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable{

  @Id
  private final String hash;

  @Field(name = "block_no")
  private long blockNo;

  private long index;

  private String from;

  // denormalized field from account
  @Field("from_is_contr")
  private boolean fromIsContract;

  private String to;

  // denormalized field from account
  @Field("to_is_contr")
  private boolean toIsContract;

  @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @AccessType(AccessType.Type.FIELD)
  @Field(targetType = DECIMAL128)
  private BigDecimal value;

  public BigInteger getValue() {
    return this.value.toBigInteger();
  }

  public Transaction setValue(BigInteger val) {
    this.value = new BigDecimal(val);
    return this;
  }

  @Indexed
  private Instant at;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a `Converter` for just one class.  But you can use `@PreLoad` to massage that data before morphia maps it back in to your class:

```
    @PreLoad
    void convertDate(final DBObject dbObject) {
        dbObject.put("someTimestamp", new Date(dbObject.get("someTimestamp")));
    }
```

Something to effect should get you what you need.  There are a few drawbacks to this approach.

1. You have to do it for each field where you find yourself in this situation.  So your "items" example above would need similar code in a `@PreLoad` method.  This hopefully doesn't happen too often so it shouldn't be overly burdensome.
2. This is a lazy conversion.  If you have queries that rely on the property being a date, they will not find records that haven't been converted yet.  One solution is to simply load/save every item via morphia.  This could potentially clobber other writes to those documents unless you version your objects.  Or you could write some javascript to run in the shell to load those documents, create a new date and simply $set back to that one field.  (You could also do something similar with morphia and some low level java driver code, of course).  Any of these solutions, without versioning enabled, would probably need some downtime depending on your application and its usage.

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.  Good luck.

Comment: ```@PreLoad```? Where does that come from? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: He's using Spring Data MongoDB, not morphia. Ah, he only specified that in a later edit. :)

Comment: Whoops.  either I missed that or he added the bit on the end after I answered.  Oh, well.  :)

Comment: I added it later, yes, but it was tagged from the beginning with spring-data, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Downvoting because this is incorrect: `You can't define a Converter for just one class.`

Answer (score 0):

For a single field you can use [PropertyConverters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/mongodb/mapping/property-converters.html):

```java
public class TimestampConverter implements PropertyValueConverter<Long, LocalDateTime, MongoConversionContext> {
    @Override
    public Long read(LocalDateTime value, MongoConversionContext context) {
        return value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime write(Long value, MongoConversionContext context) {
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue), ZoneId.systemDefault())
    }
}

class Person {
   @ValueConverter(TimestampConverter.class)
   long someTimestamp;
}
```